# Custom appsettings-to-Options-class-binding?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

We've got some more advanced Options classes that we want to use with the generic IOptions interfaces of ASP.NET Core.

Is there a way to customize the binding of an IConfiguration object to an instance of IOptions by registering some binder class or something similar at the container? We've got lots of IOptions-based-infrastructure and I want to add this custom binding with no (or next to none) touching of the code that registers the Options class.

Comment: Hmm, maybe https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36540 is what I want, and that is not yet implemented. Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can simply bind an IReadOnlyDictionary<string, MySubOptions> in an Options class and it works :-)